# How to maintain the cache of bitmap using Picasso in Android

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, picasso

Hello I am working on one android app where I require to get the the bitmap from the URL so I am using good library `Picasso` to get the bitmap and do automatically stuff like caching.

Here is my sample code

```
target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {}

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
        if(bitmap != null) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            qrCodeImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            qrCodeImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {}
};

Picasso.with(this).load(URL).into(target);
```

This code it downloads the bitmap from the URL first time then next time before close the application it pick from cache that is correct but when I close the app from the "Recent Opened Apps" then it again start to the download the bitmap from the URL.

But here I want it should always pick from cache after it download the bitmap one time. Any idea to do this using `Picasso` in Android ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is better approach to clear the Cache on App Exit. It have to be cleaned after you go out of the Activity which is showing screen in this way you can make good user experience (Thanks to Picasso, he is handling this stuff). Creating an issue there on https://github.com/square/picasso may can help you get better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso uses a builder to init the cache's which will be called when initialized. The target will automatically fetch from cache if the cache exists. However if you want to manage your own cache mechanism then you should have an instance created and accessed via your Activity/Application.

In your Application/Activity class

```
/** Other Initialization **/
private LruCache mCache;
private Picasso mPicasso;

private void setupImageManager() {
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    mCache = new LruCache(this);
    builder.memoryCache(mCache);
    mPicasso = builder.build();
}

public Picasso getPicasso() {
    return mPicasso;
}
```

For reference on how Picasso is initialized check the [Source at GitHub](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java).

Comment: OK, code which you shared in the answer will resolve my issue which I am looking ?

Comment: Yes, if you are using okhttp lib then it will cache it on disk and reload from disk. If you are using some other http lib then you need to set the cache manually and maintain it on using a downloader. After kitkat/Android 4.4 okhttp comes on the framework itself hence you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: So your above code will keep cache even if I close the app "recent tab" ?

Comment: Yes it will maintain cache. Provided you use OKHttp library for http request/responses